# What is this strange metal door and frame 12 feet up the outside wall?

Tags: walls, exterior

Any ideas on what the strange metal door and frame is in the photos?

It's about 12 feet up on an outside wall.

I'm hoping it's the source of a leak (the door is ajar), but I have no idea what it could be.

[image: strange-metal-door-thing-close-up]

[image: strange-metal-door-thing]

Comment: Looks like an ash clean out for a chimney.  Is there a fireplace or heater on the inside?  Does that section of wall contain a chimney?

Comment: Can you post pictures of what is inside that door by climbing up and opening it, and what is on the inside wall by going inside?

Comment: What does the pipe directly below it do? Given that they're directly above each other, there's likely a connection

Comment: Hmm, yes, a clean out for a chimney seems a likely thing.
I can't get up to it (at the moment, without a tall ladder), and this is in an area of my building (of flats/apartments) that I don't have access to without liaising with a neighbour.
The thing below is a central heating flue.
I'll come back with more info when I can.

Comment: Consider calling the landlord/council/building management. Seems that an exterior thing like this would be in their purview.